# Why is my custom wrapfig environment messed up?

Tags: environments, wrapfigure

I want to create a wrapper environment for `wrapfigure` in order to locally set `\initextsep` to 0. I know, it could be done differently, but this code is exhibiting strange behaviour. It moves the figure to a place *after* the paragraph it is defined in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\newenvironment{mywrapfigure}[2]{
   \begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{#2}
   }
   {
   \end{wrapfigure}
}

\begin{mywrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
   \rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{mywrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Note that all I am doing is creating a dummy environment around `wrapfigure`.
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `\wrapfigure` and `\endwrapfigure` instead of `\begin{wrapfigure}` and `\end{wrapfigure}` `wrapfigure` is no real environment in the sense of `\newenvironment`.

Comment: Other question: Why do you want a wrapper? You're losing the important 1st and 3rd optional arguments here, which may be used for fine-control

Comment: @ChristianHupfer to set `\initexsep ` locally. I also find it annoying that that setting is not automatically zero inside wrapfigure

Comment: @daleif: `\initextsep`  is completely unknown to me. Is it a TeX primitive? Do you mean `\intextsep`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i don't remember. There is a description of what it's used for in the memoir manual (Peter Wilson explained most of the mechanics behind floats). It controls (AFAIK) the distance from the top of the wrapfigure cavity to the top if the inserted material. Often you want that to be zero. But is has to be set *before* the env is used. I haven't tried, but perhaps one could make an interface keeping wrapper using xparse

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this is the wrapper wanted: I added an optional 5th argument holding the `\intexsep` value, defaulting here to `0pt`.

The `wrapfig` environment isn't a real environment defined with `\newenvironment`. In this case, it's better to use the fake environment starter and end commands `\wrapfigure` and `\endwrapfigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{mywrapfigure}{O{}mO{\wrapoverhang}mO{0pt}}{%
  \setlength{\intextsep}{#5}%  Defaults to 0pt \plus 0pt \minus 0pt
  \wrapfigure[#1]{#2}[#3]{#4}%
}{%
  \endwrapfigure%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{mywrapfigure}[8]{r}[20pt]{.4\textwidth}
  \rule{5cm}{2cm}
\end{mywrapfigure}
\blindtext[1]

\hrule
\vskip\baselineskip
\noindent Traditional: 
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}[20pt]{.4\textwidth}
  \rule{5cm}{2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The default value for the first optional argument is empty; for the second one it is `\wrapoverhang`.

Comment: @egreg: Right, I just used the values in the example on the manual starter page ;-)

Comment: I had to read the package code for finding them, they aren't specified anywhere, AFAICT.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand why the lower wrapfigure usage has a downshift. Regardless, which order `mywrapfigure` or `wrapfigure` are used, even two `innocent` `wrapfigure` will yield the second one shifted down

Comment: My impression is that `\intextsep` should be set at the outer level.

Comment: @egreg: The manual mentions `\wrapoverhang` on the 3rd page, but I found it after your first comment (didn't read that far in the manual)

Comment: @egreg: You mean `\setlength{\intextsep}` before mywrapfigure and restore it after `\endmywrapfigure`?

Comment: Yes, but this should be done *outside* the environment. Let me experiment some more.

Comment: @egreg: `\xpretocmd{\mywrapfigure}{\begingroup\setlength{...}}{}` etc?

Comment: When I leave out the second optional argument, I get an `! Undefined control sequence.
\WF@ovh ->\wrapfigoverhang`. Is that intended? Also, I am still seeing the useless top space in my document, maybe not in the mwe. Only thing that seems to help is setting `\intextsep` globally.

Comment: @oarfish: Sorry, `\wrapoverhang`, not `\wrapfigoverhang`, that was my fault. For the other problem: The MWE works, but I never guaranteed it would do so as well in the full document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, there is an interesting bug here. Try switching to `book` and add a `\chapter` right before `mywrapfigure`, then the black box is not well aligned with the text. Any idea why?

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for information, I'll take a look. Perhaps I find an explanation, but I have to test first

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've added it to the site as a question of its own: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278091/3929

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, see Davids answer to my question, we did not read the manual carefully enough, it cannot be done like this because of item 2 on the first page of the manual.

Comment: @daleif: Apparently, thanks. (And sorry for answering to your comment after some days only. I apologize!)