# wrapfig vs intextsep

Tags: wrapfigure

This is a follow up to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266431/3929

Consider the MWE below. For now, ignore that we cannot provide arguments to `\wrapfigure`, what I'm trying to understand is this:

Why is it that if I set `\intextsep` globally to zero, then no extra vertical padding is added to the wrapped figure. But it is **not** enough to set it to zero inside it wrapper env. [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14048/3929) has already answered by it does disappear in the very first one in the example. But try adding the section and the image will be shifted down.

Why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand\fig{\rule{3cm}{15mm}}

%\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\newenvironment{mw}{%
  \setlength\intextsep{0pt}
  \wrapfigure[4]{l}{3cm}
}{\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

%\section{Test}

\begin{mw}
  \fig%
\end{mw}
\kant[1]

\begin{mw}
  \fig%
\end{mw}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

The result of the MWE:

[image]

The result of adding a section

[image]

The result of globally setting `\intextsep` to zero

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says

> If you put a wrapfigure in a parbox or a minipage, or any other type of grouping,
>     the text wrapping should end before the group does.

So if you put `\wrapfig` in your environment group you have to put your (Kant) text in there as well.

Comment: Uhh, I missed that one. How annoying. Is there any alternatives? In my case the user wants to start every chapter with a small wrapped figure. I guess as long as everything is text at the start of the chapter we could just wrap the very first paragraph.

Comment: An interesting observation: if in the mwe, you add `\noindent` right after the `mw` env, then the image disappears.

Comment: @daleif If you put wrapfig in a group you are lucky to get any output:-)

Comment: @daleif can't you use a command rather than an environment to add the start of section figure? then it's much easier to control the grouping

Comment: How do you mean, we still ideally need to bring back the normal value of `\intextsep`. Actually, in this particular case we could just set `\intextsep` to zero, as the user is not a fan of `h` floats

Comment: @daleif but your group is making the settings of `\parshape` local so everything likely to go bad. If you want a local setting of \intextsep just do `\skip0=\intextsep ..... \intextsep=\skip0` or an allocated register rather than skip0 to save the value.

Answer (score 2):

As you have a quite specific wrapfig and don't want to pass options you could insert a vspace inside the wrapfig:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\def\mw{\wrapfigure[4]{l}{3cm}\ifdim\pagetotal=0pt \else\vspace{-\intextsep}\fi}
\let\endmw\endwrapfigure
\newcommand\fig{\rule{3cm}{15mm}}

\begin{document}

%\section{Test}

\begin{mw}
  \fig%
\end{mw}
\kant[1]

\begin{mw}
  \fig%
\end{mw}
\kant[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Usable, thanks. But this is of course just a simple mwe to show the problem. The real application should need all the options. In which case your solution could be mixed with the one I linked to at the beginning. Don't spend more time on it, David has already explained what the actual problem is

Comment: I feel the need to comment on this. Adding a vspace to remove the intextsep is nice, but it does not work if the width of the wrapfigure is specified as `0pt` (automatic). Somehow the vspace gets ignored in that case. So if a vspace is used, the width has to be set explicitly (for example with `\widthof{}`.